# Grafana - failed to send notification to email address

Tags: email, tcp, smtp, timeout, grafana

I am trying to setup email alerts in grafana and have made the necessary changes in the configuration file to establish a connection with an internal smtp server as well. However, I keep getting the following error when I send a test notification:

> Failed to send test alert: Failed to send notification to email
> address: email ID: read tcp  xxx:aa -> yyy:bb: i/o timeout

smtp config in custom.ini

```
#################################### SMTP / Emailing ##########################
[smtp]
enabled = true
host = IP:25
user = ""
# If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with trippel quotes. Ex """#password;"""
password = ""
;cert_file =
;key_file =
skip_verify = true
from_address = email ID
from_name = email name
# EHLO identity in SMTP dialog (defaults to instance_name)
;ehlo_identity = dashboard.example.com
# SMTP startTLS policy (defaults to 'OpportunisticStartTLS')
;startTLS_policy = NoStartTLS
```